# PHP Xpath - get all content

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to get all the text content of this div:

```
<div id="content">
    I want<br />
    all this<br />
    text.
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
//div[@id="content"]//*/text()

//div[@id="content"]/text()

//div[@id="content"]/descendant::*/text()
```

Using:

```
$contents = $result[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I think XPath: `//div[@id="content"]` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks! post as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: I can't post. Your question is closed as duplicate.

Comment: Here is the code demo https://eval.in/874238